# SSIS - ForEach Loop over multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

Problem is this: I have 3 tables. The first table is basically a list of account numbers. Second table contains a list of departments within a company, and the last contains a list of enumerated building locations(plants). The data sources in SSIS are setup (OLEDB), each pulling in every record in a column from their respective tables (plant, dept and acctnum, all of which are varchar types). I have created variables(object types) in SSIS and assigned result sets to them for each of the 3 table pulls. Row variables have been setup and assigned as well.

My goal is this: for each account number, I need to create a unique 'code' comprised of 'plant' + 'dept' + 'acctnum' and insert this concatenated result into a separate table. Each account number needs to be combined in this fashion with every plant as well as every dept.

So, a sample inserted record might look like '081350015'(first 2 digits are plant, next 2 are dept, remaining 5 are acctnum). The next inserted record would use the same account number combined with the result of the next dept record selected from the dept table and the next plant record selected from the plant table. Basically, every account number gets every combination of dept/plant.

Example:

- first record in AcctNumber table: '50001' (roughly 300 total rows in AcctNumber tbl)
- first record in Plant table: '01' (15 rows in Plant table)
- first record in Dept table: '22' (50 rows in Dept table)
- Now, build code for insert into seperate table -> '01' + '22' + '50001' -> insert '01225001'
- Still using first record from AcctNumber table: '50001'
- Still using first record from Dept table: '22'
- Now, move to Second record in Plant table: '41'
- Build code for insert into seperate table -> '41' + '22' + '50001' -> insert
- Still using first record from AcctNumber table: '50001'
- Still using first record from Dept table: '22'
- Now, move to Third record in Plant table: '18'
- Build code for insert into seperate table -> '18' + '22' + 50001' -> insert

This flow is followed until the AcctNum/Dept combination ('22' + '50001') is combined with every plant record returned from the Plant table.

Now, still using the first record returned from the AcctNum table ('50001'), we use the NEXT record returned from the Dept table ('62') and iterate back to the first record returned from the Plant table ('01') resulting in the insert of '01' + '62' + '50001' into the seperate table. So, for every Dept record returned, it will be combined with every plant record returned given the unique AcctNumber.

I know this might be confusing (or maybe not). Let me know if I need to further explain anything.

Comment: More sample data and expected output would be helpful

Comment: Why do you need to do this in SSIS?   It's a simple CROSS JOIN in SQL.

Comment: CROSS JOIN on 3, unrelated tables? I'm not sure what that SQL would even look like.

Answer (score 0):

I worked it out. Ended up cross joining the 3 tables by doing 2 at a time and storing results from each in temp tables and then cross joining those tables on the column they had in common. Thanks for the comments.